# Where can I sell domain names and earn in bitcoins?

Tags: payment, services, websites, domain-registering

I want to sell my domain names and receive payments in bitcoins. Some platforms that I know of allow to buy domain names with bitcoins but won't let you sell and earn in BTC. Any platform that allows the same?If that's not possible, any reputed bitcoin-domain escrow that may be of help?Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no sites that automatically buy domains at all that I know of. Most of the domain marketplaces don't accept Bitcoin, but the ones that do don't have much traffic.

I use bitcointalk. Just go into their Digital goods section, make a topic called [WTS] **INSERT DOMAIN**, and in the message, put in the domain registrar, how much you want for it, when it will expire, etc.

If you want, you can host an auction.

Id recommend 100% to use escrow. Here's a list of the best escrows on the forum. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=855778.0